# Does Kotlin Coroutines or any coroutine block the thread when performing DB operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to learn coroutines vs threads in Java/Kotlin. From my understanding, at least when you call a DB operation inside a thread it blocks the thread itself and wait for the response of the DB for it to be unlocked. On the other hand, Coroutines are "lightweight threads" but from my research they are just "routines" inside a thread.

So if I used a coroutine with a DB operation, will it block the thread as well hence other coroutines running inside the thread will be blocked??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, calling a long running function will block the thread the coroutine is running on.

In your example, if you have a long running db operation, you could write a function like this

```
suspend fun writeToDb(data: Data) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // write data to db here
    // return result
}
```

and you could safely call it from the UI thread like this

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.main) {
    val result = writeToDb(data)
    if (result == success) {
         // todo
    }
}
```

Making a function `suspend` does not automatically make it non-blocking. For instance, if you have something like this

```
suspend fun dontDoThis() {
    timeConsumingFunction()
}

fun timeConsumingFunction() {
    // execute long running operation in current thread
}
```

There is nothing suspending in `timeConsumingFunction`, so the `suspend` modified in `dontDoThis` is redundant (and the IDE will warn you of this), so the code will run synchronously in whichever thread it was started.